# @ symbol in JavaScript block

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a JavaScript function like this in my ASP.NET MVC 3 application.

```
function Foo()
{
   var url = "@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")";
   alert(url);
}
```

I'm confused as to why the above code **works**. I was expecting to have to escape `@Url.Action(...)` inside `<%=` tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a feature of the Razor view engine - it handles the switch between HTML/Javascript and your server-side view code so you don't need to escape it in most cases.

See Scott Guthrie's blog post on it: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx

Comment: Ah, that's the link I was looking for. Google fail

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using the new Razor view engine.

Edit: I'm assuming the JavaScript function is written inside a view file (cshtml)

Comment: Indeed I am, is this a feature?

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/wildturtle/archive/2010/10/11/exploring-asp.net-mvc-3-razor-view-engine-and-syntax-highlighting.aspx

Comment: Wow, what a pleasant surprise then :-) Stumbled on it purely by accident via a typo! Thanks.

Comment: Phil, yes...the javascript is inside one of my views.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,It works in razor view pages,but the intellisense don't work inside the "" or ''  as webform view engine.